# Chart.js - How to show loading animation before plotting chart

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) plugin to plot line chart.
I want to display loading before plotting chart.

I have tried following but nothing is happening.
Here it is showing jQuery error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: progress is not defined

But in my application it doesnt showing error.

How to show animation or loading before plotting graph?
I am using    [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/) as css framework.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"),{
  type: 'line',
  data:{
    labels: [1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 1999, 2050],
    datasets: [{
        data: [86, 114, 106, 106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 783, 2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },{
        data: [282, 350, 411, 502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3700, 5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      },{
        data: [168, 170, 178, 190, 203, 276, 408, 547, 675, 734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      },{
        data: [40, 20, 10, 16, 24, 38, 74, 167, 508, 784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      },{
        data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 26, 82, 172, 312, 433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    },
    animation:{
      onProgress: function (animation){
        progress.value = animation.animationObject.currentStep / animation.animationObject.numSteps;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="line-chart" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are basing yourself on the code shown on the [animations callbacks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-callbacks) part of the chartjs documentation.

That code is only partial. The link on the page is broken, but here is the correct full code: [progress-bar example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/a9308301e34d3fb39462a8ed24e0fd09c7f388ef/samples/advanced/progress-bar.html)

The function defined on the `onProgress` attribute is called every step of the chart animation, and thus used to fill the progress bar. The `progress` variable that is giving you the undefined error should be defined previously on your code. On the github link it's on line [#26](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/a9308301e34d3fb39462a8ed24e0fd09c7f388ef/samples/advanced/progress-bar.html#L26)

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking at there - the chart.js "progress bar" example, is for a progress bar during the *animation* as the chart is painted.

You need to have a progress bar whilst the data is loading, which is a different thing. Hence you are looking at the wrong code.

The animations in chart.js are animating the drawing of the charts, not the acquisition of the data, which is a user problem for which you'll find lots of example code everywhere.

Comment: You are telling that OP is looking a the wrong code. But you are not telling where OP has to look instead. So this is not a good answer.

Comment: The OP has the dataset inline. Hence he is not particularly talking about a 'data loading' dalay.

Comment: Could you direct where I can find the correct codes for displaying a loading gif if i were getting data from a url?